# matrix product c, core dump error

Tags: c, matrix, product

I've tried to create two matrices and do the product in another matrix, but the compiler gives an error of `core dump`. The creation of the first two matrices is right; something is wrong with the third matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int m;
int n;
int t;
int i;
int **A;
int **B;
int k;
int j;
scanf("%d",&n);
scanf("%d",&m);
scanf("%d",&t);
A=malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    A[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(int));
            }
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){  // A[n][m]
                for(j=0;j<m;j++)
                    {
                    scanf("%d",&(A[i][j]));
                    }
                }
              B=malloc(t*sizeof(int*));
              for(i=0;i<t;i++) //B[m][t]
                {
                B[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
                }
              for(i=0;i<t;i++){
                for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                    {
                    scanf("%d",&(B[i][j]));
                    }
                            }

                            int **C;


C=malloc(t*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<t;i++){{A[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(int));}


for(i=0;i<t;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
    C[i][j]=0;

        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
        {

            (C[i][j])=(C[i][j])+((A[k][j])*(B[i][k]));
        }

    }

}


}


                    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is there some reason that you are using dynamic allocation instead of variable length arrays, which have been available since C99?

Comment: In this line:
`for(i=0;i<t;i++){{A[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(int));}`
You opened the bracket **twice** and then you close it after these loops: `for(i=0;i<t;i++){ for(j=0;j<m;j++){ ...` Are you sure this is what you intended?

Comment: the excercise ask to do in this way

Comment: Do you mean "the compiler dumps core" or "the program created by the compiler dumps core"?  I assume the latter — it is rather rare to crash a compiler — but it isn't what your question says.

Comment: Hint: use separate functions to perform separate tasks. And: dont use one-letter variables, unless they are only used as indexes, or if you are a computer scientist.

Comment: It would be easier for everybody if you formatted the code in a more orthodox style.  The layout in the question is abysmal.

Comment: @fenigo69-- While the accepted answer may have fixed the problem causing the crashes, your code has issues with row and column indexing that cause errors in both input and calculation of the product matrix. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must separate memory for C, not for A. That is why when you try to access `C[i][j]` it generates this error. Change:

```
for(i=0;i<t;i++){{A[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(int));}
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<t;i++){ C[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(int));}
```

Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int m;
    int n;
    int t;
    int i;
    int **A;
    int **B;
    int k;
    int j;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&m);
    scanf("%d",&t);
    A=malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        A[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){  // A[n][m]
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            scanf("%d", &(A[i][j]));
        }
    }

    B=malloc(t*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<t;i++) //B[m][t]
    {
        B[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }

    printf("B\n");
    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&(B[i][j]));
        }
    }

    int **C;
    C=malloc(t*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        C[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            C[i][j]=0;
            for(k=0;k<n;k++)
            {

                (C[i][j])=(C[i][j])+((A[k][j])*(B[i][k]));
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP's code still has issues that cause it to incorrectly calculate the matrix product. While this code no longer seems to crash, it does not give correct output, or even take input sensibly.

Comment: @DavidBowling The question was about the core dump error. You can not say that the answer is incorrect because it does not say whether it is AxB or BxA.

Comment: Not saying that you didn't answer OP's question; the program output is clearly incorrect. Try entering a 2X3 matrix and then a 3X2 matrix.  Input is cut off because indexing is broken. Also, from comments in the code, i.e., `// A[n][m]` and `// B[m][t]`, it is clear that the intention is to find the matrix product `AB`, which should be a `n X t` matrix in this notation.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers may have fixed the problem that caused the crash, but the code is still broken. It would be nice if the variables had more descriptive names. Since each variable is declared on a separate line, you could make use of the space to provide descriptive comments about the variables.

It is conventional to reference the rows of a matrix first, and then the columns. So, I will diverge from your usage, and say that matrix `A` has `m` rows and `n` columns. `B` must then have `n` rows, and it looks like you intend for `t` to hold the number of columns in `B`. Then the product `C` will be a `m` X `t` matrix.

Your code started to go wrong when you allocated space for `B`. You allocated for `t` rows of `n` elements, when you should have allocated for `m` rows of `t` elements (by your own notation). In my code below, because I have changed the order of `m` and `n`, I allocate for `n` rows of `t` elements.

Then, for the product matrix, I have allocated for `m` rows of `t` elements, where you had allocated for `t` rows of `m` elements. The calculation of the elements of the product matrix was also wrong in your code. The `[i][j]` element of `C` is the vector dot-product of the `i`th row of `A` and the `j`th column of `B`. The way you have calculated this element, `C[i][j]` is the dot-product of the `j`th column of `A` and the `i`th row of `B`.

Here is the code with corrections. I included some input prompts, and some code to display the entered matrices and the resulting product.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

    int m;                          // rows in A
    int n;                          // cols in A
    int t;                          // cols in B
    int i;
    int **A;                        // points to first row of A
    int **B;                        // points to first row of B
    int **C;                        // points to first row of C
    int k;
    int j;

    printf("Enter number of rows in A: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Enter number of columns in A: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter number columns in B: ");
    scanf("%d", &t);

    A = malloc(sizeof(int*) * m);  // A[m][n]
    for(i = 0;i < m; i++){
        A[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &(A[i][j]));
        }
    }

    B = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);  // B[n][t]
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        B[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * t);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < t; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &(B[i][j]));
        }
    }

    C = malloc(sizeof(int*) * m);  // C[m][t]
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        C[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * t);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < t; j++){
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Matrix A:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%-5d", A[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    printf("Matrix B:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < t; j++) {
            printf("%-5d", B[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }    

    printf("Matrix product:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%-5d", C[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result of a test run:

```
λ> ./a.out 
Enter number of rows in A: 2
Enter number of columns in A: 3
Enter number columns in B: 2
2 3 4
1 3 5
3 4
5 6
7 8
Matrix A:
2    3    4    
1    3    5    
Matrix B:
3    4    
5    6    
7    8    
Matrix product:
49   58   
53   62
```